# Certificate based login Independent of server configuration

Tags: authentication, tomcat7, weblogic, jboss7.x, x509certificate

Hi I am trying to enable certificate based login and  form based login for same eb application, i have successfully configured both in same application. For this i used tomcat and springs security to achieve this.

But this configuration became tomcat specific ,  tomorrow if i want to go with JBOSS or websphere or any other server this does not apply, if i am not wrong?

So the challenge is how to enable certificate based login independent of any server for any web application using springs. I have done bit of ground work for that but all i came to know is every applications server has there own way of implementing it. So for i could not find generic way of doing cert based login.

Could some one give me initial trigger point so that i can take from there :)

> crlFile="C:\Users\certcrl.crl" keystoreFile="C:\Users\tomcat.keystore" >keystorePass="changeit" keystoreType="JKS" maxThreads="150" port="8443" > protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https" secure="true" 
>   sslProtocol="TLS" truststoreFile="C:\Users\tomcat.truststore" truststorePass="changeit" >truststoreType="JKS"/>

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your current configuration?  I'm not understanding how it came to be tomcat specific.

Comment: I have updated  confiuration i did for tomcat

Comment: Ah, I see your issue now.  You are trying to configure JBoss to require client auth SSL for certificate based authentication.  Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about JBoss.  I suggest that you change the tags so that it pings the JBoss community.